# Ruby on Rails: Delayed Job is it possible to execute one job then stop?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I want to only send out one email at a time so I have a script starting every minute. Is it possible to only send out one email and then stop the delayed job from sending the next queued jobs?

Answer (score 2):

Before you place the next job on the queue, you could look at the last job that's already on the queue, and check it's `run_at` time.  Then set the `run_at` time for your job to be one minute later.  If there's no jobs on the queue, set it to now, or one minute from now, depending on how strict you need to be about one minute between.

Answer (score 1):

You could fetch one specific job from DJ's table itself, invoke it and then destroy it, something like:

```
job = Delayed::Job.last
job.invoke_job # This will NOT destroy the job
job.destroy
```

Found it here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delayed_job/5j5BmAlXN3g

Comment: How about increasing the time in between each job? instead of each job queuing back to back I'd prefer a 10 second delay or something along those lines